# Parameterized Query using TableAdapter using existing form controls

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a form which uses a wizard generated Table Adapter based on a table which is part of my data set. I know I can setup a parameterized query using the query builder, which then adds a toolstrip to my form to accept the filter parameter. What I'd like to know is, is it possible to use an existing control (textbox) as the source of this parameter rather than having this toolstrip just appear on my form at run time and forcing the user to enter data which already appears on the form.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to use this wizard generated toolstrip if you don't want to, but you can simply reproduce what it does.

For example, for a query with a single parameter, the Visual Studio designer will generate the following click handler for the toolstrip button:

```
private void fillByCriteriaToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.tblPartTableAdapter.FillByCriteria(this.dataSet1.tblPart, partnrToolStripTextBox.Text);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

What it does is pretty straightforward. It calls a method on your TableAdapter and passes in the required parameters by reading the toolstrip controls' values.

You can easily reproduce that by creating the query directly on the TableAdapter (with the DataSet designer), and add such an handler to your own Button and use the value of your own controls.

Hope this helps.